# Adjusting simple exponential population growth model to account for predation

Tags: calculus

A population of insects will grow at a rate proportional to their current population. The population will quadruple every $9$ days. If the initial population of insects is $200$, we are asked to find the population after 5 days. I can solve this with $P(t)=200e^{kt}$ where $k=\frac{\ln(4)}{9}$. Plugging in $t=5$, I get $432$ insects.

But my problem is how do I adjust this simple model to account for the fact that, on any given day, a total of $20$ insects will be eaten or die by natural causes. Under these new circumstances, how many insects would there by after $5$ days?  Many thanks if someone can help. - Brian

Comment: "a total of 20 insects will be eaten or die by natural causes" doesn't make total sense to me, because the number of such deaths should also be proportional to the population size (or else, how do those 20 get chosen by natural causes?). Do you mean 20 when the population is 200?

Comment: "will grow at a rate proportional to their current population" implies for me that the rate is $r=ky$ and thus the growth model $y'=ry=ky^2$. However, "quadruple every 9 days" implies a constant rate of growth, so the exponential apparently remains correct.

Comment: @StefanLafon : That is only true if the population of predators grows at the same rate. If it stays constant, there will only a constant "harvest". (Spatial considerations excluded.)

Answer (score 0):

I take your point. I've assumed it's a flat 20 insects that are removed from the population daily (regardless of population size). I just used dP/dt = kP - 20 and ended up with 281 insects after 5 days.

Answer (score 0):

So you found that each day the population increases by a factor about $(1+k)$, and decreases by 20
$$
P(t+1)=(1+k)P(t)-20.
$$
Interpreting that as an Euler step of step size $\Delta t=1$
$$
P(t+1)=P(t)+(kP(t)-20)\,Δt
$$
leads back to a linear, separable differential equation
$$
P'(t)=kP(t)-20\\~\\
kP(t)-20=(kP(0)-20)e^{kt}\\~\\
P(t)=P(0)e^{kt}-20\frac{e^{kt}-1}{k}
$$
[image]